# SageMaker Estimator from EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

I have a really big confuse about how AWS integrate Docker ECR with SageMaker, even though it works from sagemaker using just the Dockerfile and train.py script executing it from another script which uses the Estimator class, it doesn't from EC2

```
from sagemaker.estimator import Estimator
import sagemaker 

estimator = Estimator(
  image_name="test_docker",
  role='arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-XXXXXXXX',
  train_instance_count=1,
  train_instance_type='local'
)
estimator.fit()
```

For this, I have the same folder with Dockerfile and train.py script and created another script called exec.py, this script has the estimator code, but when I execute it I get this error

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the
CreateTrainingJob operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 
'test_docker-2020-05-06-02-50-56-375' at 'trainingJobName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must 
satisfy regular expression pattern: ^[a-zA-Z0-9](-*[a-zA-Z0-9])*
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be anything about EC2 related. It seems the image_name can't contain underscores.